# Looping through a nested set of stdClass objects and arrays

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, stdclass

I'm trying to loop through a stdClass object ($args) which is formatted as shown below. The goal is to loop through each of the sObjects, JSON encode the values and send it to an endpoint.

I figured this would do the trick:

```
$object = $args->Notification->sObject;

    foreach($object as $item) { JSON_ENCODE AND SEND TO PASTEB.IN }
```

Except I just get a 'null' response.

If I do this:

```
$object = $args->Notification;

    foreach($object as $item) {

        $sf = $item->sObject;"

        // JSON_ENCODE $sf and send to PASETBI.N

        }
```

... I get the result of only one result posted to pasteb.in, not all of them (e.g 3 separate results as should be the case in the below table).

I've had a look at answers to other questions regarding looping through arrays/sObjects but I can't get it right. Any help would be much appreciated!

Print_r'ing this object shows this format:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [OrganizationId] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    [ActionId] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    [SessionId] => 
    [EnterpriseUrl] => https://darlston-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/33.0/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    [PartnerUrl] => https://darlston-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/33.0/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    [Notification] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
                    [sObject] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [Id] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
                            [Contact_Email__c] => test@testemail.com
                        )

                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
                    [sObject] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [Id] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
                            [Contact_Email__c] => test@testemail.com
                        )

                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Id] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
                    [sObject] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [Id] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
                            [Contact_Email__c] => test@testemail.com
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
foreach($args->Notification as $item)
{
    echo $item->Id."<br>";
    echo $item->sObject->Id."<br>";
    echo $item->sObject->Contact_Email__c."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking a look. So, I tried using this but it still just gives me one result, not the three sObjects I have in my sample. I'm not sure if this is because the page is using PHP soap?

Comment: If it's useful, here is the full page. The page is listening for XML which it's then regurgitating as $args. The important bit is in the notification function.

[link to PHP gist](https://gist.github.com/louisskelton/094e35a06b3515364262)

Comment: Hi Daniel - thanks for this, it turns out the issue was with a line of code later on that was causing the loop to abort:

`return Response::success();`

Your solution works perfectly once this is commented out - cheers!